# The jQuery Steps behaviour changes during the Google Chrome debugging

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, jquery-steps

I use [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) with tabs style for my new little .NET MVC application. Here is some tabs and one button for moving to the next step.

[image: Working with with jQuery Steps]

And by default everything is awesome!

**But!**

When I open the Google Chrome JavaScript debug window (the Sources tab, without breakpoints, and I don't do anything else) jQuery steps stops working. Only the page reloading can fix it.

[image: jQuery Steps stops working]

As you can see errors in the console indicate the presence of some errors but I can't debug it because `onStepChanging` event stops working too (by default it works and does many things when a tab is changed). The button on the first tab stops working too.

Could you help me please to understand why it can be? Why does it happen only when Google Chrome debugger opened?

It works fine in MS Internet Explorer debugger!

**Edit:**

Thanks to the flag `Pause on exceptions` which was shown me in the comments, I found that the field `stepCount` of the `state` object is equal to zero when an user clicks to a tab.

[image]

But initially when the plugin was initialised this field was equal to 4 as it should be (since we have 4 tabs).

[image]

**But!**

In the MS Internet Explorer debugger at this moment the value of this variable still equal to 4! And there this plugin works correctly.

[image]

It turns out that this error appears exactly in the Google Chrome debugger, doesn't it? How could it be possible?

Need to test it in Firefox...

Thanks!

Comment: I think this **has** to be observational error. I've never seen simply opening Chrome's dev tools have an effect like that. Even if you had, say, DOM breakpoints or similar, it would show you that it stopped on something, it wouldn't just break.

Comment: You could try turning off `Pause on exceptions` in the Javascript debugger. It's at the top right corner in the `Sources` tab.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The `Pause on exceptions` flag was turned off initially. But I turned it on and it helped me to debug some new sections of the code. I guess I found something. I'll write about it in the question.